# Why a uitextfield inside a uiscroll view doesn't scroll?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiscrollview, uitextfield, uitextview

I have a scrollview which contains a text field and a text view. I would that both two scrolled together. How can I do? Now only the text view scroll.

Precisely, I would that the title scrolls up while the user writes in the textview and, if the user decides to set it, he can scrolls up and refind the textfield.

Thanks

Comment: Why you are not going for UITableView?

Comment: I have to modify code which hasn't been written by me.

Comment: Scroll view scrolls when content size is greater than scroll view window size. If You have added text field and text view both in scroll view and if they are exceeding scroll views "content" size both will scroll.

Comment: I tried but only the text view (its content) scroll, the text field remains fixed and always visible to the user.

Comment: hmmm... Actually text view is subclass Scroll View so its scrolling well. Sorry i am not sure but also try this scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: If I try to do it with a uitableview (a row containing a uitextfield and a row containing a uitextview), could I resize the second cell in a such way that it doesn't go behind the keyboard, when the keyboard is open, and rearrange it when the keyboard is close?

Comment: Yes. Initially you should have to register for keyboard notification then You should resize table frame size when keyboard appears and when it disappears. Then use table view method scrollToRowAtIndexPath by mentioning index path of 2nd cell. It will get visible. Also if u dont want to use table view change frame size of scroll view when keyboard appears and disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

in .h

```
IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

and connect it in the interface builder
and in your .m file put this into your viewDidLoad

```
     [scrollView setScrollEnabled:YES];
     [scrollView setFrame:CGRectMake(0,55,320,180)];
     [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320,320)];
```

then put your textField and your textView inside the scroolView in the interface builder

Comment: In this way, I succeed in scrolling them together, if I hold the textfield. Obviously if I do the same thing on the text view only the text scroll... but I realized that my question isn't clear... I would that the title scrolls up while the user writes and, if the user decides to set it, he can scrolls down and refind the textfield. Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This answer is nearer to the result that I want achieve

Answer (score 0):

I want to say one thing,

Here the textfield can have only one line and the textview has multi-line of data.
So in your contest both will scroll, but you are saying one is scrolling and other is not.

In this what I am expecting is scrollview is not scrolling but the text view is showing its data(content).

Thats it.

If you want to check this, increase the textview frame upto its content and put `userInteractionEnabled as NO` and then set the scrollview content size to some what more than the textview size. Then you can observe both are scrolling.

Regards,

Satya

Comment: I mean that the uitextfield doesn't scroll not its content. I don't understand... does the uiscrollview allow the scrolling of the elements in it or what? I would that user can touch the screen to scroll and the title (uitextfield) scrolled together with the rest